# Bash - POST : send image in message content

Tags: bash, post, bash4

I would like to send POST message using bash script.In body there should be image but i don't know how to put them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cURL for that:

```
curl -F File=@/path/to/your/file http://your.url
```

If that does not work, please add more details to your question.